# 1st party cookie and user session/visit activity google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am new to GA & GTM. I want to track users session/visit activity like page views,document download etc. whatever activity user performs during the session/visit. In Omniture I do activity using evar variable. How can I do the same with GA & GTM.

Going through the document on internet I tried to do this using 1st party cookie variable in GTM. but it is not working. when i see the value for cookie variable it showing undefined and also for return type. 
A

Answer (score 0):

Logical for your question is:

- When users authenticate, the user ID should be stored in dataLayer
- When subsequent Universal Analytics tags are fired, the &uid key
  should first check if the User ID is in dataLayer
- If it is, then a cookie is written in the user’s browser with this
  User ID, and finally the value is returned to the tag
- If the User ID is not in dataLayer, GTM checks if it’s stored in a
  cookie, and if it is, the cookie value is returned
- If there is no such cookie, nothing is returned and the User ID
  parameter will not get sent

Check this [post](http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/once-userid-always-userid/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set a 1st party cookie as GA will do this itself when you put the tag on the website.  Its a lot less setup and has more metrics out of the box than Adobe Analytics.  In an aggregated fashion the activites you mention can be tracked via event tracking.

If you are looking to also track this on an individual level, then also set a user custom dimension or the userId parameter unique for each user.  This will then be associated with the out of the box metrics as above, that you can access via a custom report.